# React will component re-render if a single piece of data changes?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that contains a `table` with two columns: source and note. Source is un-editable and note has a `textinput` that the user can edit. This component contains an array **sportsData** which populates the two column layout, each element in **sportsData** representing a row of the `table`.

```
sportsData = [
    {source="climbing", note="I really like this sport."},
    {source="running", note="Meh, not a fan."},
    {source="biking", note="I need to get a bike."},
    {source="eating", note="Who isn't a fan?"}
];
```

[image]

When the user modifies one of the fields in the note column, it updates the **sportsData** state.

When **sportsData** state is updated with a single field, will this re-render my entire table? I assume that would have negative performance impacts with 100s / 1000s of rows.

Comment: Suggested read is React Reconciliation article in the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: If your table is one single big component then yeah, it will re-render all table but if you have components like Table, Row, Cell then only single cell will re-render but you need to implement this like that otherwise bad coding can lead to re-render most of the components. In short, achievable

Comment: I recommend you read the technique Virtualize Long Lists for rendering long lists of data (hundreds or thousands of rows): https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#virtualize-long-lists

Answer (score 0):

like @Zohaib-Ijaz said, using different components (row, cell, table) won't re-render the whole table.